# Is there a quick way to space out timeline frames by X amount of spacing?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

In the timeline say I have frames 1, 2, 3 and I want to pad 10 empty spaces in between them, so it would look like frame 1, 10 empty spaces, frame 2, 10 empty spaces, frame 3. Is there a shortcut to achieve this? Right now I have to manually drag my frames using "G" to space them and it is slow.

Comment: doesn't scale give the result you want?

Comment: You are right! Scale does work. Thank you. If you want to put that as a answer I will pick it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling should work, put the cursor (blue line) where you want the pivot point to be (here, at frame 1):

[image]